# Email: SMTP and php

Tags: php, smtp

Trying to send an e-mail via SMTP, its not working, any help?

```
//SMTP info
$host = "smtp.gmail.com";
$username = "taylor.mitchellstjoseph@googlemail.com";
$password = "password";
$from = "Taylor";//From email address
$to = "taylor@t-webdesign.co.uk";//Change this to your inbox


$headers = array ('From' => $from, 'To' => $to, 'Subject' => $subject);
// HTML email
//$headers .= "MIME-Version: 1.0" . "\r\n";
//$headers .= "Content-type:text/html;charset=iso-8859-1" . "\r\n";

$smtp = Mail::factory('smtp', array ('host' => $host, 'auth' => true, 'username' => $username, 'password' => $password));

//Send to you
$mail = $smtp->send($to, $headers, $message);
if (PEAR::isError($mail)) {
    echo("<h1>** Whoops! Error!. **</h1> <p>Please call us instead.</p>");
    echo("<p>" . $mail->getMessage() . "</p>");
} else {
    echo("<h1>Thank you for your inquiry!</h1> <p>Thank you for signing up for our event. Your request for our guestlist has been received. Please check your email for the confirmation.</p> ");
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Please check your PHP logs and see if there are any errors reported. The syntax looks right.

Comment: View your PHP environment variables, then find the log location and open it with a text viewer. Scroll to the end, some errors should be logged there. If you're in Windows in may be in C:\PHP5\Logs\ and in Linux it may be in /var/log/.

Answer (score 1):

Your $from might be your problem.  That isn't exactly a valid email address.  Try either changing it to a real address or omitting altogether.

Answer (score 0):

The [google documentation](http://mail.google.com/support/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=13287) says that ports 465 or 587 should be used for connections to the SMTP server. It seems that [Mail_smtp](http://pear.php.net/package/Mail/docs/latest/Mail/Mail_smtp.html) uses 25 by default. Try an explicit value of 465 or 587 with the 'port' parameter

```
$smtp = Mail::factory(
    'smtp',
    array('host' => $host,
          'port' => 465,     // explicit port 465 or 587
          'auth' => true,
          'username' => $username,
          'password' => $password),
);
```

Comment: Also have a look at the following site, it has an example that should work with smtp.gmail.com under the "Sending using authenticated SMTP" heading (and oddly enough, it does use port 25): http://www.phpmaniac.net/wiki/index.php/Pear_Mail

Answer (score 0):

It looks to my like your $from is not a valid email address. You could try replacing this with something more along the lines of "name@example.com".

However, I have had little success with the standard PHP SMTP library, so I always use the open source [phpmailer](http://phpmailer.worxware.com/) instead. It's just as easy, and sends as both HTML and plain text, produces very helpful error messages if something goes wrong, etc.

Good luck.

Comment: Hey, i tried that, i got an error every time saying the from address was invalid, it was a googlemail adress

Answer (score 0):

Note that many ISPs require you to use their own SMTP server and block other ones.